# Combine 4 tables in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, join

I have four tables and I need to extract individual cost for every owner. The price of the procedure is in proceduredetails table and the name of the owner is from owners table. The two tables do not have the same column. I have to reference the pets table and the procedurehistory table to link them.

[image]

This is my current query

```
select owners.name ||' '|| owners.surname AS Owner, sum(proceduredetails.price) as price
from owners, proceduredetails
join pets p on owners.ownerid = p.ownerid
inner join procedurehistory p2 on p.petid = p2.petid
group by owners.ownerid;
```

I got an error

> ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "owners" Hint:
> There is an entry for table "owners", but it cannot be referenced from
> this part of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply inner join instead of cross join and proper relationship. As ownerid is used in group by clause so MAX() is used for owner name because ownerid is unique. Otherwise use ow.name ||' '|| ow.surname in group by clause instead of ownerid.

```
-- PostgreSQL
SELECT MAX(ow.name ||' '|| ow.surname) AS Owner
     , SUM(pd.price) as price
FROM owners ow
INNER JOIN pets p 
        ON ow.ownerid = p.ownerid
INNER JOIN procedurehistory p2 
        ON p.petid = p2.petid
INNER JOIN proceduredetails pd
        ON pd.proceduretype = p2.proceduretype      
GROUP BY ow.ownerid;
```

Comment: what is MAX for?

Comment: @YustinaYasin if my answer is really help you then please mark it as accepted (green tick mark) also along with upvote so that others can pick it without any doubt if needed.

Comment: @YustinaYasin as ownerid is unique and it is used in group by clause so group by is working with id. that's why use max() for avoiding group by with name. otherwise you can use ow.name ||' '|| ow.surname as group by instead of id. In RDBMS you will get an error for name column if it's not used in group by clause because without aggregate function column in select clause must be placed in group by clause.